# PHP not accepting accents in POST

Tags: php, html, post, diacritics

I'm trying to submit letters with accents, â, ê, î, ô, û, through a form and I'm not getting them in POST, I have no issues with displaying letters with accents on my site.

I have the following in my header file;

```
header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
```

The default_charset on the server is also set to ISO-8859-1

I tried setting my form charset but still no luck

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">
```

Example of code that is being used

```
echo 'â, ê, î, ô, û';
if(isset($_POST['commentSubmit'])) {
  print_r($_POST);
}
echo '<form method="post" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <input type="hidden" name="submitType" value="tech" />
  <input type="hidden" name="mailType" value="feedback" />
  <input type="hidden" name="mailTypeSub" value="response" />
  <input type="hidden" name="mailLanguage" value="FR" />
  <input type="hidden" name="tName" value="Josh" />
  <input type="hidden" name="tEmail" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="feedback" value="" />
  <table border="0" width="50%" class="datatable" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Email Technican</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><textarea name="comment" cols="67" rows="10"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="submit" name="commentSubmit" value="Email Technican" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to email this technician?\')"/></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>';
```

[Output of _POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWGk6.png)

Comment: Well, what _are_ you getting?

Comment: Have you tried using UTF instead? `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: @Eugene I'm getting nothing, it's dumping all the data.

Comment: @AndyGee UTF-8 does not work for me and doesn't work to display any data which is why I'm using ISO-8859-1

Comment: I think you should paste an example of non-working code so we can fix it. Kinda difficult to see what's going on with the info provided. If UTF-8 doesn't work for you I think you have some coding/design issues that need to be resolved.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try the hexadecimal equivalents?

â

```
&#226;
```

ê

```
&#234;
```

î

```
&#238;
```

ô

```
&#244;
```

û

```
&#251;
```

**Edit:** Here's a list: http://www.codetable.net/unicodecharacters

Comment: I'm not getting any data when I dump the POST using print_r